# Understanding the Formulas for Cartesian to Hyperspherical Coordinate Transformation

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces, euclidean-geometry, spherical-coordinates, spheres

I am in the process of coding a function to convert Cartesian coordinates to hyperspherical coordinates. However, I've encountered some confusion regarding the transformation formulas.

On the [Wikipedia page for N-sphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_coordinates), the formula for hyperspherical coordinates is provided as shown in [this image](/mnt/data/44d315c8839a1eab2eed817d776555ea2faa83d6.svg).

$$
\begin{align}
r      &= \sqrt{{x_n}^2 + {x_{n-1}}^2 + \cdots + {x_2}^2 + {x_1}^2} \\[6pt]
\varphi_1 &= arccot \frac{x_{1}}{\sqrt{{x_n}^2+{x_{n-1}}^2+\cdots+{x_2}^2}} &&= \arccos \frac{x_{1}}{\sqrt{{x_n}^2+{x_{n-1}}^2+\cdots+{x_1}^2}} \\[6pt]
\varphi_2 &= arccot \frac{x_{2}}{\sqrt{{x_n}^2+{x_{n-1}}^2+\cdots+{x_3}^2}} &&= \arccos \frac{x_2}{\sqrt{{x_n}^2+{x_{n-1}}^2+\cdots+{x_2}^2}} \\[6pt]
       &\,\,\,\vdots &&\,\,\,\vdots \\[6pt]
\varphi_{n-2} &= arccot \frac{x_{n-2}}{\sqrt{{x_n}^2+{x_{n-1}}^2}} &&= \arccos \frac{x_{n-2}}{\sqrt{{x_n}^2+{x_{n-1}}^2+{x_{n-2}}^2}} \\[6pt]
\varphi_{n-1} &= 2arccot \frac{x_{n-1}+\sqrt{x_n^2+x_{n-1}^2}}{x_n} &&= \begin{cases}
    \arccos \frac{x_{n-1}}{\sqrt{{x_n}^2+{x_{n-1}}^2}} & x_n\geq 0, \\[6pt]
     2\pi - \arccos \frac{x_{n-1}}{\sqrt{{x_n}^2+{x_{n-1}}^2}} & x_n < 0.
\end{cases}
\end{align}
$$

If I interpret this for a 3D point$(x, y, z)$, I deduce the following:

$$
\begin{align}
r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2} \\
\varphi_1 = arccot\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{y^2 + z^2}}\right) \\
\varphi_2 = 2 \times arccot\left(\frac{y + \sqrt{y^2 + z^2}}{z}\right) \\
\end{align}
$$

However, when I refer to the [Wikipedia page for the 3D spherical coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system), the formula seems different:
$$
\begin{align}
r &= \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2} \\
\theta &= \arccos\frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}} = \arccos\frac{z}{r}=
\begin{cases}
 \arctan\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{z} &\text{if } z > 0 \\
 \pi +\arctan\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{z} &\text{if } z < 0 \\
 +\frac{\pi}{2} &\text{if } z = 0 \text{ and } xy \neq 0 \\
 \text{undefined} &\text{if } x=y=z = 0 \\
\end{cases} \\
\varphi &= sgn(y)\arccos\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} =
\begin{cases}
 \arctan(\frac{y}{x}) &\text{if } x > 0, \\
 \arctan(\frac{y}{x}) + \pi &\text{if } x < 0 \text{ and } y \geq 0, \\
 \arctan(\frac{y}{x}) - \pi &\text{if } x < 0 \text{ and } y < 0, \\
 +\frac{\pi}{2} &\text{if } x = 0 \text{ and } y > 0, \\
 -\frac{\pi}{2} &\text{if } x = 0 \text{ and } y < 0, \\
 \text{undefined} &\text{if } x = 0 \text{ and } y = 0.
\end{cases}
\end{align}
$$

I suspect I might be overlooking a detail or misunderstanding something. Could someone help clarify this discrepancy?

Comment: Just a difference in rearrangement. The Cartesian coordinates is symmetric w.r.t. $x,y,z$. Replace $x_1=z$, $x_2=y$ and $x_3=x$ and you're good to go.

Comment: But for the third one, they are not the same, are they? $
2arccot \frac{y+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{x} \neq sgn(y)\arccos\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}
$. I set $x = 1$ and $y = 0$ and they were not the same.

Comment: Through converting $\text{arccot}$ to $\text{arccos}$, $$2\text{arccot}\frac{y+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{x}=-\text{sgn}(y)\text{arccos}\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},$$ where I have replaced $x_1=z$ and $x_3=x$ rather than $x_1=x$ and $x_3=z$. Furthermore, I omitted the $2\pi$ term since trigonometric functions of angles are indifferent to it.

Comment: But are these two really the same? By setting $x = 1$ and $y = 0$ will get $2arccot(1) = arccos(1)$. As far as I know, these are not the same. $arccot(1) = \pi/8$ and $acrcos(1) = 0$.

Comment: You have made a miscalculation. It should be $-\text{sgn}(y)\text{arccos}\frac{{\color{green}y}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$, not $-\text{sgn}(y)\text{arccos}\frac{{\color{red}x}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$. Also, $\text{arccot(1)}=\frac{\pi}{4}\ne\frac{\pi}{8}$.

Comment: Oh yeah! now these two are the same! Thank you very much for pointing this out. But I'm still puzzled! It seems that we should reorder the $(x,  y, z)$ points in the first formula as $(z, y, x)$ and the second formula as $(y, x, z)$ for them to be the same! isn't that an issue!? because as points in space $(z, y, x) \neq (y, x, z)$!

Comment: Well, it is merely a re-orientation of space. Generally speaking, this so-called reordering $(x,y,z)\to(z,y,x)$ draws a linear mapping, with the following transformation matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}0&0&1\\0&1&0\\1&0&0\end{bmatrix}.$$ To improve your intuition, think of each point of space as a coordinates-independent entity. This makes perfect sense in cases when, for instance, relative positions of points are important. Applications are tensor calculus and mappings, but these are quite off-topic for your question.